# How to only import _(value)?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm reducing non-used import in my web project.

According to [lodash.com](https://lodash.com/), I can cherry-pick the methods I use, which is good.

ex:

```
var at = require('lodash/at');
```

But I don't know how to only import **_(value)**.

I tried the following which doesn't work

```
const seq = require("lodash/seq");
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: You mean the `_` constructor?

Comment: yes, i guess. The one in Seq classification if you check the lodash document. This function will wrap your input with a lodash object.

Comment: You're going to have to import the whole library if you want to use `_(value)` as far as I can tell. I'm not familiar with Lodash but accordingly to the docs, can you use `_.chain`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can import [chain](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chain) method. But I'm not sure if it works properly with cherry-picking.

```
const chain = require('lodash/chain');
```

P.s. check out the interesting article [Why using `_.chain` is a mistake.](https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba) and methods [flow](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flow) and [flowRight](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flowRight)

Comment: Sorry for my late response. From all the reading I found, _.chain seems cannot work properly with cherry picking. It seems you have to import the entire lodash library in order to use the constructor/chain feature. But flow and flowRight information is super useful. And I end up with using that as my solution. (although it's kinda painful when you have a helper class, and you have to import both fp functions and the regular lodash functions, just because you want to use normal lodash funtions but need the functional programming (fp) version of them to use flow...)